# Change catalog product layout view by code?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, code

My catalog product use 3 Columns Layout. The layered navigation in the right The product in the center The cart in the left. my problem when i don't have a product in the category the right column is empty. I wish when my category is empty ma catalog product transform from 3 columns to 2  columns. Can i do that by code ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the idea.

```
<?php
    $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); 

    $count_prods = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id)->getProductCount();

    if ($count_prods < 1)
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
             ->getLayout()
             ->getBlock('root')
             ->setTemplate('page/2columns-left.phtml');   

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
?>
```

You can create a new module with an observer to catch the `controller_action_layout_load_before` event. So you can put this code in the Observer.php of your module.

Take a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616489/magento-event-on-any-page-load.

Here is a tutorial on how to create a module with an observer. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Comment: Thanks where i can try to add that ?

Comment: i updated my post.